# To store multiple textbox value in session using onblur event

Tags: php, arrays, session, onblur

Here, If I write name of textbox is id from an array, then how it would be use in session.?

My code is:

```
foreach($abc as $row)
{
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="txt" id=txt_"<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
}
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).on('blur','.txt',function(){

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "view_orders_checked_array.php",
            data: {task: 'alltxt'},
            async: false
        });
 });
```

In view_orders_checked_array.php:

```
if($task == "alltxt")
{
    $_SESSION["textareaID"] = [];
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $al[] = array_push($_SESSION["textareaIDs"], $row["id"]);
    }
    print_r($al);
}
```

So, how it would possible to store textbox value in session array.?

Comment: did you start the session?

Comment: Yeah..!! in the start of view_orders_checked_array.php.